# Converting html special character in excel

Tags: excel

Could anyone please suggest a function/formula used in worksheet to convert html special character to HTML entity, thanks
E.g.
™ to `&trade;`
® to `&reg;`

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question is a two part.

1. Do you only need to convert a certain set of these special chars?
2. Do you need to convert **All** supported?

Answer 1:

```
Public Function ConvertHTMLTag(data As String) As String
    data = Replace(data, "&trade;", "™")
    data = Replace(data, "&reg;", "®")
    ConvertHTMLTag = data
End Function
```

Answer 2:

Repeat for all chars in http://www.webmonkey.com/2010/02/special_characters/

To make this a bit easier, I would try to put this list in to an Excel sheet with in two columns. One for the special tag and the other with it's evaluated char.

Write a formula in a 3rd column to create your code for you...

```
="data = Replace(data, "&Char(34)&A1&Char(34)&", "&Char(34)&A2&Char(34)&")"
```

Once you have your VBA code you've created in Excel, a simple copy and paste in to the function above will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Use this function to encode from html special character to string

```
Function HTMLToCharCodes(ByVal s As String) As String

    With New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
        .LoadXML "<p>" & s & "</p>"

        HTMLToCharCodes = .SelectSingleNode("p").nodeTypedValue
    End With

End Function
```

Input: `&amp;`, return: `&`